# Multiple Filters on VBA Excel doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue in VBA Excel, I'm trying to code a user input to filter out some columns in a database but when I executed only the last column in my code that end up getting filtered. Any help fixing this is appreciated. I'm trying to make the each column to stay filtered for each user input.

Here is my code:

```
    Sub InputFilter()

Dim strInput As String
Dim strInput1 As String
Dim strInput2 As String

strInput = InputBox("Enter your value to filter WPP")
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=strInput 'User Input for desired WPP

strInput1 = InputBox("Enter your Product Category")
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=strInput1 'User Input for Product Category

strInput2 = InputBox("Enter your Manufacturing Code")
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=strInput2 'User Input for Manufacturing Code

    'Sorting FACodes
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data Domestic").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("C4:C351"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data Domestic").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to filter using the same range or it overwrites existing filters. Your code would benefit from a `With` block to reduce repetitive code

Comment: What is the last filter that is applied? Is it the FA Codes filter of the strInput2 filter?

Comment: I use the same range on all the filtering codes, the last filter is to filter to manufacturing codes with strInput2. I tried using ```with``` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. Remove the rest of the code below when testing

```
Dim F1 As String, F2 As String, F3 As String

F1 = InputBox("Enter your value to filter WPP")
F2 = InputBox("Enter your Product Category")
F3 = InputBox("Enter your Manufacturing Code")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:B351")
    .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=F1
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=F2
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=F3
End With
```

You also need to specify the sheet (Swap `Sheet1` with your sheet name)

Comment: Sorry I had some typos. try again Just tested and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I got runtime Error "1004" from that, 
Update: I got it Working with this instead `ActiveSheet.AutoFiterMode = False`
and just delete the `Selection.AutoFilter` after each input

```
Sub InputFilter()

Dim strInput As String
Dim strInput1 As String
Dim strInput2 As String

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
strInput = InputBox("Enter your value to filter WPP")
'Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=strInput 'User Input for desired WPP

strInput1 = InputBox("Enter your Product Category")
'Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=strInput1 'User Input for Product Category

strInput2 = InputBox("Enter your Manufacturing Code")
'Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=strInput2 'User Input for Manufacturing Code

    'Sorting FACodes
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data Domestic").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("C4:C351"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data Domestic").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```